# spark in java, Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.4

Tags: apache-spark, jackson, spark-streaming, jackson-databind

I'm trying to run a simple spark streaming app in Java. But it failed at `ssc.receiverStream`,showing `Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.9.4`. I checked my jackson version, it's 2.6.0. How does 2.9.4 come? Below screenshot is all the external libraries I'm using. Most of the other answers related to this issue is in scala. How can I solve it in java?

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myCustomizedReceiver").setMaster("local[2]");
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(1000));
JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = ssc.receiverStream(new myCustomizedReceiver());
```

[image]

Comment: How are you running this code? The spark/hadoop libs may already be giving you some jackson jars. Last: Why don't you just upgrade your own jackson dependency?

Comment: You can check the actual versions used by running `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: @ernest_k, I tried upgrade to 2.9.4. But it shows the same error.